# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector

Tags: java, casting, jtable, tablemodel

I'm trying to fill tableModel with data from a list of lists of Objects `readExcel.readSheet(0)`, using following code :

```
 TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(
    new Vector<List<Object>>(readExcel.readSheet(0)
       .subList(1, readExcel.readSheet(0).size())), 
    new Vector<Object>(readExcel.readSheet(0).get(0)));
```

but I'm getting this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Vector
```

I think it's about instanciating a Vector via a list, but through [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28java.util.Collection%29) of Vector, we can see it's possible to instantiate a Vector using a collection.

What's the problem with my code snippet ?

Comment: I think you need to read bit more about casting and how it works. for your solution you can use addAll method in vector to add elements in arraylist

Comment: Yes, you do not understand "cast".  Which is not at all unusual, as it is a difficult concept to grasp and probably more misunderstand it than understand it.

Comment: @Vinay can you suggest me a good place where I can read about it ? between thanks you for the addAll method trick

Comment: Casting with generics is tricky. It doesn't seem obvious to realise that you cannot cast from List[A extends B] to List[B].

Comment: Casting with generics is mostly tricky because it's not a real operation, but only something you do to fool the compiler.  The runtime hasn't a clue that an object is a `Vector<Object>` vs a `Vector<String>`.

Comment: It's important to understand that two different things are involved here:  The *thing* (a Java object), and the *reference variable* (a "pointer" or "name" for the object).  The object itself has a type (eg, `Vector`) which cannot be changed.  The reference variable has a type as well, which may or may not exactly match the type of the object it references.  Where there's a difference, the reference variable's type can only ever be some superclass of the actual object's type -- runtime checks associated with the cast operation assure that this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure, but I think the answer is that generics do not respect sub types. E>g. if B extends A, then you might think that you can cast List[B] to List[A], but I think that you actually cannot. Although you can addAll to put all the items from list into list.

Thus

```
List<ArrayList<Object>>
```

is not a type of

```
List<List<Object>>
```

and the cast fails because the return type of readExel is the former not the latter.

The reasons for this are mostly to do with obscure edge cases. THere is an item about it in Effective Java

```
public class test {

static class Foo {

}

static class Moo extends Foo {

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Moo> list = new ArrayList<Moo>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        list.add(new Moo());
    }

    List<Foo> listFoo = (List<Foo>) list;

}
```

}

Generates a complier error because

```
List<Moo>
```

is not a sub type of

```
List<Foo>
```

So your code should work if you replace

```
Vector<List<Object>>
```

with

```
Vector<ArrayList<Object>>
```

Comment: Thanks @phil for explanations, but readExcel.readSheet(sheetNumber) returns List<List<Object>>, changing Vector<List<Object>> with Vector<ArrayList<Object>> didn't work either :)

Comment: In that case can you split the line up and use the stack trace so we can see if it is creating the vectors which is the problem, or if it is the Table which is trying to cast?

Comment: The two types, Vector and ArrayList, share AbstractList as a common ancestor, so it's possible for an interface to be designed to accept either.  However, this common ancestry does not mean that you can substitute one where the other is expected.   Has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: Vector implements List Hot Licks

Answer (score 2):

"cast" is an instruction from the programmer to the compiler; it says "it is theoretically possible that the type I am passing here is not a subtype of the required type, but I know that it will be at runtime, so do not give an error saying that this is the wrong type."

The compiler can only cast one type to another if the two types are in an inheritance line together, i.e. if they are inherited, directly or indirectly, one from another.

So I'm going to guess that one of the arguments in your somewhat convoluted constructor and/or method calls requires an ArrayList, and you are passing a Vector.  If the constructor or method requires an ArrayList, you cannot pass a Vector to it.

Comment: I would have said "The compiler *will only allow* a cast of one type to another if the two types are in an inheritance line together".

Answer (score 1):

You can cast a superclass into subclass and vice versa.

But Vector and ArrayList doesn't share any parent-child relationship.

Both have common ancestor though (`List > Collection >iterable`).

So you can cast a vector to and from a List. But cannot cast to arrayList directly. E.g.

```
public class test {

static class Foo {

}

static class Moo extends Foo {

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Moo> list = new ArrayList<Moo>();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        list.add(new Moo());
    }

    List<Foo> listFoo = (List<Foo>) list;

}
```

}

Generates a complier error because List is not a sub type of List

So your code should work if you replace Vector> with >

Comment: So your code should work if you replace Vector> with > ? I think you missed something here

Comment: You can only cast an object to what it is.  You cannot, eg, cast a reference to a HashMap to make it a LinkedHashMap reference, but you can cast a reference to a LinkedHashMap to be a HashMap, and you can cast a LinkedHashMap reference that is stored in HashMap reference variable to be stored in a LinkedHashMap.